# filling in (...rest) parameters with an array?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Some as3 functions handle overloading by allowing for an arbitrary number of parameters using the convention:

```
public function doSomething( ... rest ):void;
```

I am in a situation where I need to pass all the values of an array (of arbitrary length) into this type of function...  I am not sure how to do this.  Suggestions?

Here is a hack solution, but it is not extensible:

```
switch (args.length) {
case 0: doSomething(); break;
case 1: doSomething(args[0]); break;
case 2: doSomething(args[0], args[1]); break;}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out [Function#Apply()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Function.html#apply()). It lets you pass the parameters as an array.

```
doSomething.apply(contextObj, args);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://johncblandii.com/2010/06/as3-tip-pass-rest-arguments-w-other-arguments-to-a-function.html) is a very good tip to pass the rest parameter between functions.