# AS3 arguments

Tags: actionscript-3, function, arguments

Why do you think the code below does not work? 
What would you change/add to make it work?

Any help is appreciated..

```
function TraceIt(message:String, num:int)
{
    trace(message, num);
}

function aa(f:Function, ...args):void
{
    bb(f, args);
}

aa(TraceIt, "test", 1);

var func:Function = null;
var argum:Array = null;

function bb(f:Function, ...args):void
{
    func = f;
    argum = args;
    exec();
}

function exec()
{
    func.apply(null, argum);
}
```

I get an ArgumentError (Error #1063):

```
Argument count mismatch on test_fla::MainTimeline/TraceIt(). Expected 2, got 1.
```

..so, the passed parameter (argum) fails to provide all passed arguments..

..Please keep the function structure (traffic) intact.. I need a solution using the same functions in the same order.. I have to pass the args to a variable and use them in the exec() method above..

regards

Comment: Added it to the post above.. thanks..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution.. after breaking my head : )

```
    function TraceIt(message:String, num:int)
    {
        trace(message, num);
    }

    function aa(f:Function=null, ...args):void
    {
        var newArgs:Array = args as Array;
        newArgs.unshift(f);
        bb.apply(null, newArgs);
    }

    aa(TraceIt, "test", 1);

    var func:Function = null;
    var argum:*;

    function bb(f:Function=null, ...args):void
    {
        func = f;
        argum = args as Array;
        exec();
    }

    function exec():void
    {
        if (func == null) { return; }
        func.apply(this, argum);
    }
```

This way, you can pass arguments as variables to a different function and execute them..

Thanks to everyone taking the time to help...

Answer (score 1):

When TraceIt() eventually gets called, it's being called with 1 Array parameter, not a String and int parameters.

You could change TraceIt() to:

```
function TraceIt(args:Array)
{
     trace(args[0], args[1]);
}
```

Or you could change exec() to:

```
function exec()
{
     func.apply(null, argum[0].toString().split(","));
}
```

...as it appears when you pass "test", 1, you end up with array whose first value is "test,1". This solution doesn't work beyond the trivial case, though.

Comment: thanks but this is a very simple version of the actual code. I mean the TraceIt represents any function passed... meaning it differs all the time..

Answer (score 1):

Change your bb function to look like this:

```
function bb(f:Function, args:Array):void
{
    func = f;
    argum = args;
    exec();
}
```

As you have it now, it accepts a variable number of arguments, but you are passing in an array(of the arguments) from aa.