# Flash AS3 ... (rest) parameter

Tags: actionscript-3

OK, so we all know that using the ... (rest) parameter in a function lets us pass any number of arguments, as in the example in the Adobe AS3 manual:

```
function traceArgArray(x: int, ... args) {

for (var i:uint = 0; i < args.length; i++) {

trace(args[i]);

}

} 

traceArgArray(1, 2, 3);
```

BUT, what I would love to be able to do is to have the option of EITHER passing individual arguments OR passing arguments from an already-existing array:

```
myArray:Array = new Array(1,2,3);
```

and so:

> traceArgArray(myArray);

As I've written it here, the function treats myArray as a single object, so the output is 1,2,3--a representation of the array as a whole, not the individual contents of the array.

In order to transform myArray into a comma-delimited list that the rest operator would recognize as a list of individual elements, I tried this:

```
traceArgArray(myArray.join());
```

but that didn't change the output.  It looks like in this case the argument is being interpreted as a single string rather than a comma-delimited list.

So, the puzzle I hope someone can help me with can be expressed in either of two ways:

Is it possible to get the rest parameter to treat an array argument as a comma-delimited list of arguments?

-or-

Is there a way I can transform an array into a comma-delimited list and then pass that list to the function AS a comma-delimited list (rather than a long string) so that the rest operator can interpret it correctly?

The basic thing I want to do--be able to pass arrays of values into functions that accept any number of arguments--would seem to be of general use, so perhaps there is a work-around I'm not seeing because I'm obsessing over the rest operator itself.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass arguments from an array to an Actionscript method with ...(rest) argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260875/pass-arguments-from-an-array-to-an-actionscript-method-with-rest-argument)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636853/filling-in-rest-parameters-with-an-array

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [Function.apply()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Function.html#apply%28%29). In your case it would look like this:

```
myArray:Array = new Array(1,2,3);

function traceArgArray(x: int, ... args) {
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        trace(args[i]);
    }
} 

traceArgArray.apply(this, [0].concat(myArray)); // [0] being the first argument (x)
```

Answer (score 1):

See this

[AS3 ... (rest) parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971475/as3-rest-parameter)

and this is referenced in the above:

[AS3 arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972460/as3-arguments/972518#972518)

and this could be useful as well

[filling in (...rest) parameters with an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636853/filling-in-rest-parameters-with-an-array)

Comment: +1 for using the search and referring to previously asked questions

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case it is more about handling the args then trying to call the method different...

```
    traceArgArray(1, 2, 3);

    var myArray:Array = new Array(1,2,3);   
    traceArgArray(1,myArray,"hello");


    myArray.push(["a",23,"her", 1.456, ["--","||",12,11] ]);
    traceArgArray(1,myArray,"hello");

    private var theArgsILike:Array= new Array();

    private function traceArgArray(x: int, ... args):void {

    //Creates the args you expect...
        theArgsILike.push(x);
        addArgs(args);

    // Trace both old and new style args
        trace("NEW Call: ------");
        trace("\n \targs: ------");
        for (var i:uint = 0; i < args.length; i++) {    
            trace(args[i]);
        }
        trace("\n \t The Args I Like: ------");
        for ( i = 0; i < theArgsILike.length; i++) {
            trace(theArgsILike[i]);
        }
        trace("\n");

        theArgsILike = new Array();
    }

    //splitting each array in its parts to add them on theArgsILike
    private function addArgs(inArgs:Array):void{
            //check if it is array 
        for each(var arg in inArgs){
                    if( Class(getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(arg))) == Class(getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(inArgs)))  ){
                    //spilt iteratively
                        addArgs(arg);
                    }
                    else{
                    // add arg 
                        theArgsILike.push(arg);
                    }
        }
    }
```